# subset as for loop / if-statement

Tags: r

I just started programming in R and I'm currently trying to do some exercises.

My task is it to write a subset for some csv dataset as a for-loop / if-statement.

The subset looks like this and is doing its job:

```
subset(data_sat_csv, Altitude <= 2000, Acronym)
```

And my try for a loop was like this:

```
for (i in 8:ncol(data_sat_csv)) {
  if(i > 2000){ 
    next
  }
    else(print(data_sat_csv$Acronym))
  
}
```

Instead of getting the same data as in the subset, it prints the whole column multiple times. So there should probably be a "break"-statement anywhere(?).

It should loop over the 8th column once and skip NA values.

Any suggestions on how to rewrite it so it works the same as the subset?

This is probably a minor issue but thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess `i > 2000` should be `data_sat_csv$Acronym[i] > 2000` and `else(print(data_sat_csv$Acronym))` more like `else { print(data_sat_csv$Acronym[i]) }`. And you could simplify it to: `if(data_sat_csv$Acronym[i]<= 2000) { print(data_sat_csv$Acronym[i])}`.

Comment: Your code doesn't use `i` to index the column `data_sat_csv$Acronym`, that's why the entire column is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Absent a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we'll use the `mtcars` data to illustrate a solution for subsetting with a `for()` loop.

```
subset(mtcars,mpg > 30)
```

generates the following:

```
> subset(mtcars,mpg > 30)
                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Fiat 128       32.4   4 78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4 75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4 71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Lotus Europa   30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```

We set an output data frame to NULL so it doesn't disappear after the `for()` loop completes and its environment is recycled, and then write to it each time the condition in the `if()` statement is true, as we iterate from `1:nrow(mtcars)`.

The basic idea is that for each row in `mtcars` we check whether `mpg > 30`. If the comparison is `TRUE`, we write a row to the output data frame, `resultData`. We loop over the rows, not the columns in order to extract the rows that fulfill the same condition we used in `subset()`.

```
resultData <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(mtcars)){
     if(mtcars[i,"mpg"] > 30) resultData <- rbind(resultData,data.frame(mtcars[i,])) 
}
resultData
```

...and the result is:

```
> resultData
                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Fiat 128       32.4   4 78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4 75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4 71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Lotus Europa   30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```

If we want to include only certain columns in the output data frame, we can modify the `rbind()` function to write specific columns. For example, if we want to write only `mpg` and `cyl`, we'd use the following code:

```
resultData <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(mtcars)){
     if(mtcars[i,"mpg"] > 30) resultData <- rbind(resultData,data.frame(mtcars[i,c("mpg","cyl")])) 
}
resultData
```

...and the output is:

```
> resultData
                mpg cyl
Fiat 128       32.4   4
Honda Civic    30.4   4
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4
Lotus Europa   30.4   4
>
```

Comment: Thank you :) I think I understand what I have to do.